# My Sql query is correct but it is not affecting any row.?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

The Query.

```
UPDATE data.full 
   SET ISBN = ''
     , second_title = 'Fundamental of Bones Biology'
     , author = 'Weimann, P. Joseph.'
     , sec_author = 'Sichar, Harry'
     , editor = ''
     , Edition = '2nd'
     , volume = ''
     , publisher = 'Henery Kimpton'
     , publ_place ='London'
     , publ_year = '1955'
     , pagination = '508 p'
     , price = ''
     , subject1 = 'Anatomy'
     , subject2 = ''
     , Item_type = 'Books'
     , classno = ''
     , bookshelf = 1 
 WHERE title = '%Bone And Bones %'
```

When I don't use wildcard. I get syntax error.

Comment: Use `WHERE title like  '%Bone And Bones %'` instead of `WHERE title =  '%Bone And Bones %'`

Comment: And, for future reference, try the same `WHERE` clause with a `SELECT`, to make sure it actually finds anything.

Comment: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0570 sec) It show this when i use LIKE

Comment: Even when i use select query no row is showing but it also not showing any error

Comment: You have a white space after second Bones and %, remove that and try. Otherwise your statement looks fine, as suggested by others you have to use LIKE to compare strings instead of '='.

Comment: Just curious, what other units of 'pagination' do you use - apart from 'p', and does it not matter that some books have more than two authors/editors?

Comment: @Strawberry - I'm with you too - there's so many problems with this dataset... Looks like he needs a minimum of 7 _additional_ "base" tables, plus cross-ref ones (title, author, editor, edition/volume/other..., publisher, subject, item_type)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
WHERE title like '%Bone And Bones %'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "LIKE" instead "=" ON WHERE clause

EDIT:

```
WHERE title LIKE '%Bone And Bones %'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a white space after second `Bones` and `%`, remove that and try. Otherwise your statement looks fine, as suggested by others you have to use `LIKE` to compare strings instead of `'='`.